# SQL equivalent of Math.Floor() in c#

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just want to convert `10.111` to 10 based on some condition in the following Query

```
Select 
    case when 2=1 then
        CONVERT(decimal(10,3), 10.111)
    else
        CONVERT(decimal(10,0), 10.111)
    end
```

But it return 10.000
How can i get 10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `CASE` expression as a whole must all evaluate to the same datatype. The only way of having one branch evaluate to `decimal(10,3)` and the other to a different datatype would be to do a cast to `sql_variant`

```
Select 
    case when 2=1 then
        CONVERT(decimal(10,3), 10.111)
    else
        CAST(FLOOR( 10.111) AS SQL_VARIANT)
    end
```